# How to generate the same random numbers using a seed in python and in excel?

Tags: python, excel, random, random-seed

I need to generate some random numbers using a seed and the results in python and in "random number generator" from data analysis in exel have to be the same.

They both use the Mersenne Twister as the core generator. However, I've tried using the same settings for both of them and I still got different results for each. For the "RNG" in excel,I have to answer what is the distribution, how many numbers I need and seed. I need and "uniform" distribution, 5 numbers, and "2519" as a seed. **How can I make the two results match?**

In Excel (2016), I'm not using any code, I'm using the "RNG" tool from the Data Analysis toolpack. In python, this is the code I'm using to generate the random numbers:

```
import random
random.seed(2519)
for i in range(5):
    print(random.uniform(2, 98))
```

Since I'm using the same configuration, I expected the result I got from excel:

```
20,29352702
26,21167638
50,5962096
89,57689138
91,71562853
```

However, my code printed:

```
87.86907401941477
4.168159315747875
95.86785037507858
92.44359253465223
77.63783740240486
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the code used in Excel? And which version of Excel? On which platform/device?

Comment: What exactly are you using in Excel to generate random numbers?

Comment: I am not sure, but probably they probably won't give the same results because of differences in the implementation. One solution (although messy) is to use xlwings to call the python random function inside excell or the excell RND function inside python. Check it out https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings

Comment: @Olaf I'm using the "random number generator" from the Data Analysis toolpack.

Comment: Also Ruby uses the same algorithm, but with different results: `71.74757467452324
69.45040960262058
86.66516698538922
35.20417390631426
20.989002720294106`

Comment: The only guarantee with a particular implementation of seed is that *within that implementation* of the RNG the same seed produces the same random numbers. There's no standardisation of seeds so no reason to expect them to match. You'll either have to read from excel the generated random numbers or write to excel. xlwings is way to go.

Comment: @AndrewAllen thank you for the answer! I thought the seed worked for every implementation. Too bad that it isn't like that. I'll try to use the xlwings.